# Comparing DB2 DATES - IBM i dates not compatible with DB2 dates SQL

Tags: sql, date, db2, comparison-operators

I'm trying to create a report shows orders that are late, due current month, next month, etc. pulling data from IBM i server (AS/400) using DB2 SQL. However, I'm running into issues with comparison operators. I have a potential solution, but it is so tedious that it would make my code significantly longer and very prone to errors.

For example, I am pulling customer orders by Request Date:

```
  SELECT C6D0NB /* REQUEST DATE */                   
    FROM MBC6REP /* CUSTOMER ORDER FILE */             
   WHERE C6DCCD = '1' /* ONLY ORDERS, NOT QUOTES */   
ORDER BY C6D0NB DESC /* DATES DESCENDING ORDER */
```

which results in:

```
 Request 
 date    
118/08/28 
118/06/29 
118/06/15 
118/06/07 
....
117/07/21 
117/06/14 
117/04/14 
117/03/01
```

So, this "Request Date" (C6D0NB) field is labeled as a "date" format within my ERP system (Infor XA). I can use comparison operators to use static comparisons (e.g. between January 1, 2018 and January 15, 2018, inclusive):

```
   SELECT C6D0NB /* REQUEST DATE */                     
     FROM MBC6REP /* CUSTOMER ORDER FILE */               
    WHERE C6DCCD = '1' /* ONLY ORDERS, NOT QUOTES */ AND 
          C6D0NB >= '1180101' AND                              
          C6D0NB <= '1180115'                                  
 ORDER BY C6D0NB DESC /* DATES DESCENDING ORDER */
```

with results:

```
  Request 
  date    
 118/01/15 
 118/01/15 
 118/01/12 
 118/01/12 
 ....
 118/01/03 
 118/01/03 
 118/01/03 
 118/01/02
```

However, when I want to use the "CURRENT DATE" function, I run into errors. When I query:

```
SELECT CURRENT DATE   
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

I receive the expected:

```
CURRENT DATE
02/12/18
```

I can use the DAY, MONTH, YEAR functions as expected:

```
SELECT DAY(CURRENT DATE)
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Which returns:

```
DAY 
12
```

I cannot however, combine the two:

```
  SELECT C6D0NB /* REQUEST DATE */                    
    FROM MBC6REP /* CUSTOMER ORDER FILE */              
   WHERE C6DCCD = '1' /* ONLY ORDERS, NOT QUOTES */ AND
         C6D0NB >= CURRENT DATE                              
ORDER BY C6D0NB DESC /* DATES DESCENDING ORDER */
```

which gives me the error:

```
 Comparison operator >= operands not compatible.
```

If I try using MONTH with "Request Date",

```
  SELECT MONTH(C6D0NB) /* REQUEST DATE */           
    FROM MBC6REP /* CUSTOMER ORDER FILE */            
   WHERE C6DCCD = '1' /* ONLY ORDERS, NOT QUOTES */  
ORDER BY C6D0NB DESC /* DATES DESCENDING ORDER */
```

I receive this error:

```
Argument 1 of function MONTH not valid.
```

How do I create a dynamic report to query, for example, all dates within current month? I can run the following code, but it's extremely tedious:

```
    SELECT C6D0NB /* REQUEST DATE */              
    FROM MBC6REP /* CUSTOMER ORDER FILE */               
    WHERE C6DCCD = '1' /* ONLY ORDERS, NOT QUOTES */ AND
    MONTH(TO_DATE((CONCAT(
             CONCAT(
             (CONCAT(SUBSTRING(C6D0NB,4,2), '/')),
             (CONCAT(SUBSTRING(C6D0NB,6,2), '/'))),
             SUBSTRING(C6D0NB,2,2))), 'MM/DD/YY')) = MONTH(CURRENT DATE) AND
    YEAR(TO_DATE((CONCAT(
             CONCAT(
             (CONCAT(SUBSTRING(C6D0NB,4,2), '/')),
             (CONCAT(SUBSTRING(C6D0NB,6,2), '/'))),
             SUBSTRING(C6D0NB,2,2))), 'MM/DD/YY')) = YEAR(CURRENT DATE)  
    ORDER BY C6D0NB DESC /* DATES DESCENDING ORDER */
```

Is this really the most concise way to code it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C6D0NB is not actually a Date column, it's a numeric column whose values is interpreted by your ERP as a date in CYYMMDD format.

The IBM i and it's prior incarnations the iSeries and AS/400 have supported true date types for a long time.

Unfortunately, they are not used in many older applications...

Best solution, use a UDF to convert from the numeric value to an actual date.  You could write your own, or download Alan Campin's [iDate](http://www.think400.dk/downloads.htm) tools...

Then you'll be able to simply do...

```
  SELECT C6D0NB /* REQUEST DATE */                    
    FROM MBC6REP /* CUSTOMER ORDER FILE */              
   WHERE C6DCCD = '1' /* ONLY ORDERS, NOT QUOTES */ AND
         idate(C6D0NB,'*CYMD') >= CURRENT DATE                              
ORDER BY C6D0NB DESC /* DATES DESCENDING ORDER */
```

Actually, from a performance perspective, it'd be better to convert the date to a CYYMMDD numeric.  Alan's package includes such a function...

```
  SELECT C6D0NB /* REQUEST DATE */                    
    FROM MBC6REP /* CUSTOMER ORDER FILE */              
   WHERE C6DCCD = '1' /* ONLY ORDERS, NOT QUOTES */ AND
         C6D0NB >= convertToiDate(CURRENT DATE, '*CYMD')                              
ORDER BY C6D0NB DESC /* DATES DESCENDING ORDER */
```

This allows indexes on C6D0NB to be used...

Alternately, you can create a "Dates" or "Calendar" Table.  besides using it to convert from numeric dates to actual date types...it's useful for lots of other set based operations...in any DB.

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty looking at a CYYMMDD date but it can be done with the built in [varchar_format](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007110.html) function.

I'm comparing from position 2 because that's where the "1" is this is the 21st century.

```
select * from mytable 
where mycyymmdd date =
substring( varchar_format(current timestamp,'CCYY/MM/DD'), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicating from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56022968/3441253) for sake of ease finding only:

---

Since none of variants suited my needs I've came out with my own.

It is as simple as:

`select * from yourschema.yourtable where yourdate = int(CURRENT DATE - 1 days) - 19000000;`

This `days` thing is leap year-aware and suits most needs fine.

Same way `days` can be turned to `months` or `years`.
No need for heavy artillery like `VARCHAR_FORMAT`/`TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`.