# SQL: from integer to date

Tags: sql, date, datetime, db2-400

I have an integer which represents a date. eg: 20230530 and I need to convert it to a date format. I tried

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,convert(char(6), DATE)) FROM MY_TABLE
```

But it outputs an error:

```
SQL Error [42704]: [SQL0204] CONVERT in *LIBL type *N not found

org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.sql.DBSQLException: SQL Error [42704]: [SQL0204] CONVERT in *LIBL type *N not found.
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.executeStatement(JDBCStatementImpl.java:133)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeStatement(SQLQueryJob.java:509)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.lambda$0(SQLQueryJob.java:440)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:168)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeSingleQuery(SQLQueryJob.java:427)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.extractData(SQLQueryJob.java:808)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.SQLEditor$QueryResultsContainer.readData(SQLEditor.java:3092)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.lambda$0(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:121)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:168)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.run(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:119)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetViewer$ResultSetDataPumpJob.run(ResultSetViewer.java:4454)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCSQLSyntaxErrorException: [SQL0204] CONVERT in *LIBL type *N not found.
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.createSQLExceptionSubClass(JDError.java:948)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:745)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCStatement.commonPrepare(AS400JDBCStatement.java:1790)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCStatement.execute(AS400JDBCStatement.java:2096)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.execute(JDBCStatementImpl.java:327)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.executeStatement(JDBCStatementImpl.java:130)
```

Eventually I would like to get the age of a person = date of today - birth date

Comment: It's imperative you specify which database you are using. Databases DO NOT share the same sql this is especially true with date and time.

Comment: I can see an IBM sql error [SQL0204] I am going to go with you are using DB2. Refer to this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47932883/2043275

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert does not exist in DB2 for IBM i, see [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=functions-scalar)

You can get a date type from an int using `date(to_date(char(myintdate), 'YYYYMMDD'))`
and calculate the age using `int((current date - birth_date) / 10000)`

```
with t1 (myintdate) as (
    values int(19630514)
  )
select date(to_date(char(myintdate), 'YYYYMMDD')) as myDateDate,
       int((current date - date(to_date(char(myintdate), 'YYYYMMDD'))) / 10000) as age
from t1;
```

| MYDATEDATE | AGE |
| --- | --- |
| 1963-05-14 | 60 |

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of ways to treat that integer as a date or timestamp. There is also an age function (although the result is an integer representing number of years, months and days e.g. 200002 = 20 years, 0 months, 2 days) e.g:

```
SELECT 
    TO_DATE(date_integer, 'YYYYMMDD')  
  , age( TO_DATE(date_integer, 'YYYYMMDD') )  / 10000 age_in_years
from my_table
```

| 1 | AGE_IN_YEARS |
| --- | --- |
| 2003-05-30 00:00:00.000000 | 20 |
| 1976-01-17 00:00:00.000000 | 47 |

Note using `to_date(20030502,'YYYYMMDD')` results in a timestamp, if you want a date value instead then use `date(to_date(20030502,'YYYYMMDD'))`

The following is an examination of how one might use age:

```
select
   date(TO_DATE(date_integer, 'YYYYMMDD'))   as my_dt
 , (d.age_yymmdd / 10000)                    as age_years
 , int(left(right(d.age_yymmdd,4),2))        as age_months
 , int(right(d.age_yymmdd,2))                as age_days
, (d.age_yymmdd / 10000) 
  || ':' || left(right(d.age_yymmdd,4),2)
  || ':' || right(d.age_yymmdd,2)            as age_ymd
 , d.age_yymmdd
from my_table t
join table  (
  select age( date(TO_DATE(t.date_integer, 'YYYYMMDD')) ) age_yymmdd
  from my_table
  ) as d on true
```

| MY_DT | AGE_YEARS | AGE_MONTHS | AGE_DAYS | AGE_YMD | AGE_YYMMDD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2003-05-30 | 20 | 0 | 2 | 20:00:02 | 200002 |
| 1976-01-17 | 47 | 4 | 15 | 47:04:15 | 470415 |
| 2003-05-30 | 20 | 0 | 2 | 20:00:02 | 200002 |
| 1976-01-17 | 47 | 4 | 15 | 47:04:15 | 470415 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OfMT-CAt)

**nb** regarding `JOIN TABLE` seen in the above this is a "substitute" for a lateral join see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75085066/2067753

Answer (score 0):

In Your SELECT Statement you declared **char(6)**, change that to **char(8)**. Verify the Length of **20230530**.

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,convert(char(8), '20230530'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
WITH 
indata(datestring) AS (
  SELECT '20230530' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
)
SELECT
  TO_DATE(datestring,'YYYYMMDD')
FROM indata;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a date without a timestamp, use `TO_DATE()` to convert an integer to a date datatype, then use `VARCHAR_FORMAT()` to format it as `YYYY-MM-DD` or any other format:

```
SELECT VARCHAR_FORMAT(TO_DATE(datetime, 'YYYYMMDD'),'YYYY-MM-DD')
from MY_TABLE
```